# To extract a particular column from existing excel which has 2 precision value(3.55). Help me make, it has 1 precision value(3.5,3.9)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to extract a particular column  from existing excel which has 2 precision float value(3.55,3.98). Please help me to make it has 1 precision value(3.5,3.9).

```
try {
    InputStream myxls = new FileInputStream("D:\\Amrutha\\SIMPL\\DashBoardReport20110228.xls");
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(myxls);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);                  

    HSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator = new HSSFFormulaEvaluator(sheet,wb);
    CellReference cellReferenceSource = new CellReference("AA17");
    HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);

    for(Iterator rowIter = sheet.rowIterator(); rowIter.hasNext(); ) {
       HSSFRow  row = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
       HSSFCell cellSource = row.getCell(cellReferenceSource.getCol());

       evaluator.setCurrentRow(row);
       if (cellSource != null) {
           //HSSFFormulaEvaluator.CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
           CellValue cellValue= evaluator.evaluate(cellSource);
           //CellValue cellValueTarget= evaluator.evaluate(cellTarget);
           FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Amrutha\\SIMPL\\DashBoardReport20110228.xls");

           if(cellValue != null) {

              switch (cellValue.getCellType()) {

              case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                  System.out.println(cellValue.getBooleanValue());                      
                  break;
              case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                  // HSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
                  HSSFDataFormat format = wb.createDataFormat();
                  HSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
                  style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0.0"));
                  // cellSource.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                  cellSource.setCellStyle(style);
                  System.out.println( cellSource.getCellStyle());
                  // style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat(".0"));
                  System.out.println(cellValue.getNumberValue());
                  cellSource.setCellValue(cellValue.getNumberValue()); 
                  // cellSource.setCellStyle(style);
                  // cellSource.setCellValue(cellValue.getNumberValue()); 
                  // System.out.println(cellValue.getNumberValue()); 
                  wb.write(fout);
                  fout.close();
                  break;
              case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                  System.out.println(cellValue.getStringValue());                      
                  break;
              case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                  System.out.println(cellValue.getErrorValue());                      
                  break;
              case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                  System.out.println("");                      
                  break;                  
                  // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never happen
              case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                  System.out.println("CELL_TYPE_FORMULA");
                  break;
              default:
                  System.out.println("null");
                  break;
              }
           }
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("null");
        }
     }
  } 
  catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.print("Exception in main "+e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in simple java rather than poi.

The `Cell.getNumericCellValue` will return you a Double, so just format it to the precision you want.

```
        Double d = new Double(cellSource.getNumericCellValue());
        System.out.println ("Double value "+ d);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
        System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

or even simpler

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
                System.out.println(df.format(cellSource.getNumericCellValue()));
```

Output from my trial

```
Double value 1.808702175543886
1.8
```